# Is there normal way to rewind (or jump to specific frame) in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to implement a handcrafted video playback program for dataset marking.

Here is the code that i am using right now:

```
class MarkingTool:

    def __init__(self, video_path_, csv_path_):
        self.video_path = video_path_
        self.csv_path = csv_path_

        if not os.path.exists(self.video_path):
            print('There is no such video file')
            sys.exit()
        if os.path.exists(self.csv_path):
            print('Such csv file already exists')
            sys.exit()

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path)
        self.orig_fps = self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)  # only for OpenCV 3
        self.num_frames = int(self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))  # only for OpenCV 3
        self.cur_frame = None
        self.cur_pos = -1
        self.is_paused = False
        self.play_speed = 1.0
        self.min_speed = 0.25 / self.orig_fps  # 1 frame per 4 sec

        self.events = {}
        self.csv_file = open(self.csv_path, 'w', newline='')
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_file, dialect='excel')

        cv2.namedWindow("Marking Tool", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.setMouseCallback("Marking Tool", self.menu_mouse_click)

    ## Code for dataset marking ##
    ...

    def read_next_frame(self):
        ret, self.cur_frame = self.capture.read()
        if not ret:
            self.close_program()
        self.cur_pos = int(self.capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))

    def show_cur_frame(self):
        self.draw_main_menu()
        cv2.imshow("Marking Tool", self.cur_frame)
    
    def rewind_frames(self, frames: int):  # if - it is rewind, if + it is skip
        pos = self.cur_pos + frames - 1
        pos = 0 if pos < 0 else pos
        pos = self.num_frames - 1 if pos >= self.num_frames else pos
        self.cur_pos = pos
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, self.cur_pos)
        self.read_next_frame()
        self.show_cur_frame()

    def rewind_seconds(self, seconds: float):
        frames = int(seconds * self.orig_fps)
        self.rewind_frames(frames)

    def change_speed(self, change: float):
        self.play_speed += change
        self.play_speed = self.min_speed if self.play_speed < self.min_speed else self.play_speed
    
    def close_program(self):
        print("Exit")
        self.write_events()
        self.csv_file.close()
        self.capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        sys.exit()
    
    def play_pause(self):
        self.is_paused = not self.is_paused

    def run_tool(self):
        while self.capture.isOpened():
            if self.is_paused:
                k = cv2.waitKey()  # indefinite delay
            else:
                self.read_next_frame()
                self.show_cur_frame()

                fps = int(self.orig_fps / self.play_speed)  # modifying playback speed
                k = cv2.waitKey(fps)

            if k & 0xff == 8:  # backspace
                print('rewinding back 5 sec')
                self.rewind_seconds(-5.0)
            elif k & 0xff == 13:  # enter
                print('enter')
            elif k & 0xff == 27:  # esc
                self.close_program()
            elif k & 0xff == 32:  # space
                print('playing/pausing playback')
                self.play_pause()
            elif (k & 0xff == 81) or (k & 0xff == ord('a')):  # 'left' arrow
                print('rewind 1 frames')
                self.rewind_frames(-1)
            elif (k & 0xff == 82) or (k & 0xff == ord('w')):  # 'up' arrow
                print('change speed +0.2x')
                self.change_speed(0.2)
            elif (k & 0xff == 83) or (k & 0xff == ord('d')):  # 'right' arrow
                print('skip 1 frames')
                self.rewind_frames(1)
            elif (k & 0xff == 84) or (k & 0xff == ord('s')):  # 'down' arrow
                print('change speed -0.2x')
                self.change_speed(-0.2)

            elif k == -1:  # when nothing is pushed
                continue
            else:  # to find out numeric code for unknown button
                print(k)
```

It works completely fine on my computer, but the problem is that on another machine after pressing "a" (left arrow key / rewinding 1 frame) jumps not one frame back but many more.

Though "self.cur_pos" state shows that it really jumped only 1 frame back, while visually I can say that it skipped more than 10 frames.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any other alternative to using cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES for controlling video flow and jumping 1 frame back and forth?
2. Do you see any obvious (or subtle) bug that is connected to the problem stated above?

Comment: the issue is **different video files**, what kind of data they contain (how they're encoded). seeking in video files is a difficult problem and often not exact, in that you can't jump to arbitrary positions, only to **keyframes**. ffmpeg doesn't work with frame numbers because video files might not have that information. it has to work with timestamps. look up what "[group of pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures)" means, and what are keyframes (I-frames) vs. P/B-frames. try `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` instead of pos_frames.